# Is there a way to graphically combine the results from multiple runs of profvis

Tags: r, profiling

I am just starting to sink my teeth into profiling with R and find the `profvis()` function quite intuitive to use because of it's graphical features.

My understanding is that each time you run `profvis()` the results you get are just a sample that can differ quite dramatically because of processes like garbage collection. For this reason I am currently running the `profvis()` function three or four times and visually inspecting the output for consistency before attempting to optimise certain parts of code.

My question is, can I run `profvis()` multiple times (in a loop for instance) and then display the flame graph and other output in an aggregated fashion, or is there a good reason why you should not do this?

MWE:

```
x <- rnorm(10000)
y <- rnorm(10000)

profvis({
  plot(x, y)
})
```